# Ansible/jinja2: Use filter result in if condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

is it possible to use the result of Jinja2 filters in conditions in ansible playbooks?

I'm trying to get this working, but without success:

```
{% if (item | ipv4) %}{{ item }}{% else %}{{ lookup('dig', item) }}{% endif %}}
```

where *item* in my current test is set to *localhost* (and could be any other private or public domain).

Should do: If *item* is an IPv4 address the adress should be returned, otherwise it should be "converted" (DNS lookup with *dig*) to an IPv4 address - but it always is returning the hostname.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance
Matthias

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
{{ item if (item | ipv4) else lookup('dig',item) }}
```

Comment: Thank you! With Ubuntu 16.04 you need also the packages `python-netaddr` and `python-dnspython`